# Bullets appear as question marks on Android, PDF, ok on PC and on Liquid Mode

Tags: html, css

The following code renders as bullets on windows desktop Adobe reader Renders as bullets on Android version 13, latest version of Adobe acrobat reader app, but, in liquid mode only In normal mode on the android app, the bullets show up as question marks! I don't use any css style for the bullets at all

pure html -> https://codepen.io/kutty-nakku/pen/MWqLWLp `<div><ul>...</ul></div>`

Any help/ideas will be appreciated

Thanks

Tried several combinations with and without the DIV as there was a note somewhere that lists don't show up properly in mpdf when they are in a table

Comment: Maybe set a default font.

Comment: You add php and mpdf as tag, where is your php code? This is simple HTML CSS question

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan the rest of the code is very simple as well... so i had not included it. But point taken... next time onwards, I shall include full code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that the alphabet "f" was also appearing as "?"

This was with freeserif as the font setting

I changed it to Arial and not only "f" appeared well, but the bullet problem also went away, on all platforms!

I guess it was something to do with the font. Strange that it worked on the PC and in liquid mode.

Ah well.....

Answer (score -1):

What if you write the style of the bullets explicitly?

```
    li {list-style-type: disc;}
```

Comment: This could be a valid comment, but an answer should not be a question, and the suggested code should best be tested before.

Comment: I understand your opinion, and totally agree with you.

But, this case based on a bug and anyone can try to test it. My theory was based on the fact that if it's not the font itself, then perhaps the regional setting is turned on (about which nothing was said), and perhaps instead of "disks" a regional numbered list was substituted, which most likely may not be included in the font. This was the reason for the proposal to try this method, which does not make sense to test on any other device, because, the code above works without any remarks.